# How to import a React proptypes typed component as type any into a React Typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have quite a big component library done in proptypes, and we are moving to typescript.

So when I was moving a .jsx component to be a .tsx component an imported .jsx component suddenly started throwing typing errors, there is nothing currently wrong with the imported component and I can't just rewrite it typescript as it is used everywhere and it would be more effort at the moment than worth.

to get around this I did as follows (lots of intervening code removed)

```
import MyReactComponent from 'path/to/component';

const FixedMyReactComponent: any = MyReactComponent;

return <FixedMyReactComponent/>
```

it works, my errors went away, but I find this to be irritating, I would instead like not to have to make a FixedMyReactComponent and set a type for it locally, and (as I already said) I don't want to put in the time right now to fix the fact that typescript isn't understanding my component, so instead I would like to find some way to globally tell typescript ignore type errors you get from a js / jsx and only report errors from .ts / .tsx.

I suppose it would be something like

```
declare module '*.jsx' {
  var _: React.Component<any, any>;
  export default _;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to have the effect I want.

Comment: you can try with type `JSX.Element`

Comment: @antoineso hey I clarified the problem, as I understand it you are suggesting I use JSX.Element instead of any which I guess is nice, but it is not per se using the any that bothers me, it is having to do it locally in the component via declaring a new variable which seems very hacky. I would like some sort of global solution so I don't have to make FixMyReactComponent without having to spend the time to make my classical react proptype validated component play nice with with typescript component as I don't have time for that right now.

Comment: Does this help? [route.component does not have any construct or call signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66583322/2873538)

Comment: @jimmy no, I don't want to make the proptypes file a typescript file right now. I want to use the proptypes file inside a typescript file. That gave me an error unless I did MyComp2 any = MyComp - I find that inelegant and would like to be able to just say at a global level - when importing proptypes components into typescript components have typescript compiler treat proptypes components as though they were of type any - assuming of course proptypes library will handle its own proptypes files. If this might be problematic and have wide ranging side effects, authoritatively comment on why.

Comment: I am not sure if the error you're experiencing is related to TSX vs JSX as a whole. As a POC I can import a .JSX component with proptypes into a .TSX component without adding typing such as `:any`. I can pass props to this and there are no errors. Maybe posting more of your code is required.

Comment: `const FixedMyReactComponent: React.ComponentType<any> = MyReactComponent` would be better than just `any`. This says that it is a react component that takes any props.

Comment: @im_baby - I can as a general rule import proptypes into typescript without problems, but in this case I experienced problems until I did the any hack. I am pretty sure it is a very edge case situation, like there is nothing wrong with my proptypes per se, but am passing in a property not defined by proptype for passing onward via a ...rest param to some subcomponent. Perhaps what I want - that typescript ignore what it thinks are problems with non-typescript components or at least that I can configure it to do so without an any hack - is incompatible with how typescript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are time-constrained in doing the work now you could use [`// @ts-nocheck`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#ts-nocheck-in-typescript-files) (added in TypeScript `v3.7` for this exact use case) at the top of all your newly created `.ts?(x)` files and gradually remove them over time. This will type check **NOTHING** basically treating the file as javascript while exporting whatever explicit or implicit types are defined in the file. You may also want to loosen the [`compilerOptions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#compilerOptions) something like [this](https://gist.github.com/mizchi/31aef7dd1e2f96d0caf8356fef97a050) until you can tighten them later on.

---

If you do have some time to complete the conversion you could look into using the [`react-javascript-to-typescript-transform`](https://github.com/lyft/react-javascript-to-typescript-transform) npm package from lyft. It is deprecated but seems to get the job done, at least for the prop-type to type conversions.

Starting with a simple js prototype example from react.

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Install the module...

```sh
npm install -g react-js-to-ts
```

Run this command to convert all js files to ts.

```sh
react-js-to-ts ./**/*.js
```

The package then replaces all files from js with `prop-types` into `.tsx` with prop interfaces.

```
type GreetingProps = {
  name?: string
};
class Greeting extends React.Component<GreetingProps, {}> {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Works for functional components and class components. I am not sure how this behaves with state types or other non-typed code you may have in your component but this would be a good step forward. The state could easily be typed as `any` for the time being anyway. Also not sure how well this package performs with complex prototypes like `PropTypes.shape` and `PropTypes.arrayOf`.

If I were you I would verify all the changes, but any conversion errors should be very apparent via type errors. No need to use a fake js to ts component conversions. Even after running this code, if you run into too many type errors you can turn off [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) mode and even add `// @ts-nocheck` where needed until your team has the bandwidth to address the bad types.

Honestly, I think this is the best approach, any other way of trying to trick the typescript compiler is gonna be more difficult and hacky than this or provide inconsistent types from your original prototype definitions.

Comment: sure I used that to transform the proptypes based component into a typescript one that then gave me the error about the lower level component not working, as a normal rule of engineering you are right that it is better to fix the component instead of trying to hack it, but have some real world constraints such as - very big codebase so incremental improvement best, lower level component used very many places - these two constraints mean I don't want to fix the lower level component right now. But after going through saying all that - I think ts-nocheck is the correct answer for me.

Comment: I awarded the bounty and marked it as accepted answer, imho tsc-nocheck is the part of the answer that solved the problem, so it would be better to highlight that at the top of the answer and then say something about when you do want to turn that component into typescript use this package - etc. etc.

Comment: Yeah good point there are always tradeoffs, I added a note at the top about using `// @ts-nocheck` if you are time-constrained. Really that comment was added for this exact use case in their own words "to make migrations easier". Glad that helped.

Answer (score 2):

move your proptypes to a type then you can just type your component.

```
import { FC } from 'react'

type FixedMyReactComponentProps = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const FixedMyReactComponent: FC<FixedMyReactComponentProps> = ({name, id}) => {
...
}
```

But if you must type it as any. You declare the return type:

```
const FixedMyReactComponent = (): any => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: yeah the problem then is that I don't want to rewrite the component I'm importing into my react typescript as react typescript, I want to be able to do something, hopefully globally in some configuration, so that when I import a proptypes validated component into a typescript validated component I don't suddenly get validation errors, otherwise I would have to rewrite multiple files every time I decide to rewrite one.

Comment: obviously I want to maintain validation errors or warnings on the proptypes level, and I want validation of the typescript typing, but I don't want the typescript file to say this proptypes file you imported doesn't validate by our typescript rules. Which I am achieving by declaring a new variable of type any and assigning the imported component to it. I just don't want to always have to do that - I would like to do it globally.